# Python logic bug: my variable is assigned correctly and after some "for" and "if" statements it becomes None without touching it

Tags: python, variables, nonetype

As I said in the title the variable dots in this code pice becomes a None value after some logic statements, without touching the variable at all. As you can see in the code, there are two different statements of "print dots". I've made the experiment and the first one gives the output "[(1,1,1),(1,1,1)..." as is assigned before. However the second one gives me the output "None". Someone can tell me why this happens and if there is any way to correct it?

```
def detectDots(surface):
   dots = [(1,1,1),(1,1,1),(1,1,1),(1,1,1),(1,1,1),(1,1,1),(1,1,1),(1,1,1)]
   print dots
   for y in range(0,480):
       for x in range(0,640):
            color = surface.get_at((x,y))
            if color.r > 250 and color.g < 70 and color.b < 80:
                inDots = True
                notInDots = []
                for i in range(0,8):
                    print dots
                    if math.sqrt((abs(x - dots[i][0])*abs(x - dots[i][0]))+(abs(y - dots[i][1])*abs(y - dots[i][1]))) < 20:
                        dots[i] = (((dots[i][0]*dots[i][2]+x)/(dots[i][2]+1)),((dots[i][1]*dots[i][2]+y)/(dots[i][2]+1)),(dots[i][2]+1))
                    else:
                        notInDots.append(i)
                        inDots = False
            else:
                dots = None
```

Comment: A small improvement for the code: `dots = [(1,1,1)] * 8`

Comment: not really, I know that in this case that's better but this block is part of a bigger code and those turples are suposed to be different later. I only wrote 1s to be able to index on them, to change them.

Answer (score 8):

My guess is that the line

```
dots = None
```

is responsible for setting `dots` to `None`.

Since your second print already prints `None`, this means that the first color at `(0,0)` does not match

```
if color.r > 250 and color.g < 70 and color.b < 80:
```

Removing the outermost else branch or just replacing the line `dots = None` with `pass` will leave dots to be a non-`None` value.

Comment: That's ridiculous. What would make you think that?

Comment: Of course! Thank you very much... I supose I should have seen that... Probably is because I have been 9 hours programming :).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried placing a debugging statement right before the line dots = None?

I would try something along the lines of

```
import code
code.interact(local=locals(),banner="Check dots = None")
```

immediately preceding your line

```
dots = None
```

Then you can see which surface location does not meet your r,g,b conditions and verify that you are correctly reading the r,g,b values.

Here's a blog link (not mine) that explains how to use some Python debugging tools
http://aymanh.com/python-debugging-techniques#launching-an-interactive-console-with-codeinteract